# Stopping getline in C

Tags: c, signals, stdin

Here I'm trying to get an user input with `getline`. Upon receiving an interrupt `^C` I want it to signal getline to stop and resume with my program instead of terminating it.

I tried to write a newline to stdin but apparently that doesn't work.

```
fwrite("\n", 1, 1, stdin);
```

So what would be a way to achieve this?

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain why this is an unclear question?

Comment: If you don't want `SIGINT` to terminate your program, you can either block it (`sigprocmask()`), or install an appropriate signal-handler (`sigaction()`).

Comment: @EOF That is not what I'm asking. I'm able to catch the signal, and I need a way to somehow tell getline to stop reading stdin.

Comment: *Well, it sounds like you want to install a signal-handler.* So go forth and read `man sigaction`.

Comment: @PCLuddite - In stdio.h? [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yeah, I realized its a POSIX thing.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, supposing that you are writing for a POSIX environment, you can prevent a `SIGINT` from interrupting your program by installing a custom signal handler for it, or by setting its disposition to `SIG_IGN`.  Whether either of these approaches will cause `getline()` to return prematurely is unclear, however.  Some I/O functions resume after a signal.  GNU `getline()`'s behavior in this regard does not appear to be documented.  You might be out of luck.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: As far as the manpage is concerned, `getline()` can't return  `EINTR`. As best as I can tell, the only ways to break out of `getline()` asynchronously would be a) manipulating the return address in the `ucontext_t*` in the signal-handler for `SIGINT`, or b) call `getline()` in a separate thread, and `pthread_cancel()` it. Obviously, this requires `getline()` to be a cancellation-point, which is permitted but not required.

Comment: @EOF, yes, `getline()` cannot return `EINTR`.  That does not necessarily mean that it must resume after being interrupted by a signal (it could instead return its documented error code, `-1`) but it does *suggest* that `getline()` will resume.  Note also that `getline()` being a cancellation point is irrelevant for the case where a thread is already blocked in that function.  A deferred cancellation request is acted upon at the time that a cancellation-point function is *called*.  The `pthread_cancel()` approach could work if the thread is made asynchronously cancellable, though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html `If a thread has cancelability enabled and a cancellation request is made with the thread as a target while the thread is suspended at a cancellation point, the thread shall be awakened and the cancellation request shall be acted upon.`

Comment: @EOF, ok, you're probably right, but it's not entirely clear to me whether "suspended" is the the state of a thread that is blocked on I/O.  The term is not explicitly defined for threads (as opposed to processes), and only a few functions are documented as causing a thread to be "suspended" (but those few *are* explicitly documented to do so).  Those include `pause()` and `wait()`, among others, but not, say, `read()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: My understanding is that `pthread_cancel()` is usually implemented via signals (and explicitly designed to make this conforming), and `getline()` presumably at some point (directly or indirectly) calls `read()`, which returns with `EINTR` on being signaled and causes cancellation. If you're unconvinced, feel free to ask a question about it. I hear that's popular on this site.

Comment: @EOF, good idea.  [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769098/what-does-it-mean-to-posix-that-a-thread-is-suspended).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code resembles this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Code here (point A)
    getline(lineptr, size, fpt);
    //More code here (point B)
}
```

Include `<signal.h>` and bind `SIGINT` to a handler function `f`.

```
#include <signal.h>

//Declare handler for signals
void signal_handler(int signum);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Set SIGINT (ctrl-c) to call signal handler
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    //Code here (point A)
    getline(lineptr, size, fpt);
    //More code here (point B)
}

void signal_handler(int signum) {
    if(signum == SIGINT) {
        //Received SIGINT

    }
}
```

What I would do at this point is restructure the code so that any code after point B is in its own function, call it `code_in_b()`, and in the handler call `code_in_b()`.

More information: [Signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html)