# What does it mean to POSIX that a thread is "suspended"?

Tags: c, posix, language-lawyer

In the course of commentary on [a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747675/stopping-getline-in-c), a subsidiary question arose about at what point a cancellation request for a pthreads thread with cancelability `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` can be expected to be acted upon.  References to [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09) and a bit of lawyering ensued.  I'm not much concerned specifically about whether I was mistaken in my comments on that question, but I *would* like to be sure I understand POSIX's provisions correctly.

The most pertinent section of the standard says

> Whenever a thread has cancelability enabled and a cancellation request has been made with that thread as the target, and the thread then calls any function that is a cancellation point [...], the cancellation request shall be acted upon before the function returns. If a thread has cancelability enabled and a cancellation request is made with the thread as a target while the thread is suspended at a cancellation point, the thread shall be awakened and the cancellation request shall be acted upon.

What, though, does it mean for a thread to be "suspended"?  POSIX explicitly defines the term for processes, but not, as far as I can determine, for threads.  On the other hand, POSIX documents thread suspension to be among the behaviors of a handful of functions, including, but not limited to, some of those related to synchronization objects.  Should one then conclude that those serve collectively as the relevant definition of the term?

And as this all pertains to the question that spawned this line of inquiry, given that POSIX does not specify thread suspension as part of the behavior of `read()`, `fread()`, or any of the general file or stream I/O functions, if a thread is not making progress on account of being blocked on I/O, does that necessarily mean it is "suspended" for the purposes of cancellation?

Comment: The IEEE 1003.1 (POSIX) standard explicitly claims that it is aligned with the ISO/IEC 9899 (C) standard. The C standard cites [ISO/IEC 2382 (Information Technology Vocabulary)](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:2382:ed-1:v1:en) for its lingo. Unfortunately, not even ISO/IEC 2382 defines _suspended_, and even uses that word in some of the definitions. What I conclude from that is that "suspended" is considered a core English word, suitable for use in explanations. My personal interpretation of suspended is "the state of a thread not currently using processor time".

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, the alignment with C is a useful observation, thanks.  I find "not currently using processor time" to be a troubling interpretation, however, for it seems like it would cover threads that *could* be running, but have been preempted.  That doesn't seem to match up -- every indication is that thread suspension is a state in which a thread is *prevented* from running even if CPU would otherwise be available for it.  It may indeed be that the C and POSIX standards assume that a natural interpretation should apply, but the details matter, and they are unclear (to me).

Comment: It seems natural to me to think that runnable threads that are not running are, for lack of a better word, suspended. On a heavily loaded `n`-core processor, there might be `>n` _runnable_ processes, but at most `n` of those can be made _running_; All others must be _not-running_, or as POSIX _might_ have it, "their execution is suspended" awaiting their turn. What do you think? Is a runnable thread waiting for a running thread's time quantum to expire suspended? How about a running thread whose quantum expires and, even though still runnable, is switched out? What about breakpointed threads?

Comment: POSIX's [Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) has the following gems: ***3.281*** _Preempted Process (or Thread)_:  _A running thread whose execution is suspended due to another thread becoming runnable at a higher priority. **3.287** Priority Inversion_:  _A condition in which a thread that is not voluntarily suspended (waiting for an event or time delay) is not running while a lower priority thread is running. Such blocking of the higher priority thread is often caused by contention for a shared resource._

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, those are good finds.  They make we wonder whether POSIX is in fact consistent at all with regard to what it means for a thread to be suspended.  If "not currently running" is indeed the intended standard, then the thread cancellation provisions are *much* stronger than I had thought.

Comment: "waiting for an event or time delay" seems helpful. The description of the [`aio_suspend`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/aio_suspend.html) function begins, _The `aio_suspend()` function **shall suspend the calling thread** until at least one of the asynchronous I/O operations referenced by the list argument has completed, until a signal interrupts the function, or, if timeout is not NULL, until the time interval specified by timeout has passed._ I can only agree that the intended definition of "suspend" is "pause/interrupt" without a more formal definition in place.

Comment: It comes to mind that maybe the imprecision in the language of _suspend_ gives flexibility to implementors of ["green threads"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) libraries (when multiple userland threads are multiplexed onto a single kernel thread). In such a scenario, the userland threads could cooperatively yield to each other and the kernel is blissfully unaware of the thread hopping below it. A synchronous `write()` by a userland thread would become an asynchronous `aio_write()` followed by a hop to another thread. What meaning "suspension" has in such a scheme is hard to guess.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, perhaps you're right, but to whatever extent the specification allows such variety of implementation that it cannot be used to predict the behavior of conforming implementations, it's useless.  I actually looked into filing a request for clarification with the Open Group, but without a print copy of the standard I don't have enough information (page / line numbers) to submit such a request.

Answer (score 3):

A suspended thread is one that, as you say, is blocked on a socket read, waiting for a semaphore to become available, etc.

Given that POSIX implementations vary at the tricky edges, and that there is the potential for a thread to be blocked in a function that is not a cancellation point, it might be that relying on cancellation in code that is to be ported might be more trouble than it's worth.

I've never used it, I've always chosen to have code to explicitly instruct a thread to terminate (normally a message down a pipe or queue). This is very easy with a Communicating Sequential Processes or Actor Model system.

That way clean up can be done under one's own control, freeing memory, etc. as necessary. I've no idea whether a cancelled thread will clean up its memory (I suspect not), or whether there is the option for an at_exit() type thing (there may be). On the whole I think that application behaviour is more thoroughly controlled if there is only one single way a thread can exit.

==EDIT==

@JohnBollinger,

The language used `If a thread has cancelability enabled and a cancellation request is made with the thread as a target while the thread is suspended at a cancellation point` could be interpretted as `IF a thread has cancelability enabled AND IF cancelled and IF implementation suspends blocked threads AND IF the thread is blocked THEN the thread shall be awakened...`. In other words, they're leaving it up to the implementer of the POSIX subsystem.

Cygwin's implementation of select() does not (or at least did not) result in the thread being suspended. Instead it spawns a polling thread per file descriptor to test for signalable activity, due to the fundamental lack of anything quite like select() in Windows (it gets close, but no cigar. Win32 select() works on only sockets). Implementations of select() back in the 1980s often worked this way too.

It might be for reasons like this that POSIX is reluctant to clearly define when a thread is suspended. Historically many implementations of select() were like this, making it a minefield for a standards committee to say when a thread might or might not be suspended. Of course the complexities caused by select() would also apply to a process but as POSIX does define a suspended process it does seem odd that they couldn't / didn't extend the definition to threads.

It might be down to how threads are implemented; you can conceivably have a POSIX implementation that doesn't use OS threads (a bit like the early implementations of ADA back in the days when OSes didn't do threads at all), and in such an implementation a blocked thread might not be suspended (in the sense of taking no CPU cycles) at all.

Comment: "A suspended thread is one that, as you say, is blocked on a socket read, waiting for a semaphore to become available, etc.".  Actually no, I *don't* say that.  In particular, I am doubtful whether POSIX defines a thread blocked on a read to be suspended.  I would be delighted to hear your basis for such a claim -- that's the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Cleanup on thread cancellation can be done by (surprise!) `pthread_cleanup_push()/pthread_cleanup_pop()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, that's fair enough. I didn't say that POSIX defines it that way either, but of course it is common for implementations to suspend a blocked thread. I've added to my answer

Answer (score 2):

> Definition of suspend in the context of threads:
>
> **3.107 Condition Variable**
>
> A synchronization object which allows a thread to suspend execution, repeatedly, until some associated predicate becomes true. A thread whose execution is suspended on a condition variable is said to be blocked on the condition variable.

From: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

This is not a direct answer, just a definition – too large for a comment.  Blocked == suspended.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that.  I account it as defining the behavior of `pthread_cond_wait()` to include thread suspension.  Other functions (`wait()`, `sleep()`, ...) are also documented to cause thread suspension, however, so that cannot be a complete definition.

Comment: 'Synchronization object' is not necessarily local to the code - it may be a kernel implemented object instead.   What we need to find is the discussion  (intent) behind the definition's development to be sure.  Any help there?

Comment: I've been studying aspects of POSIX on and off for some time, but I'm afraid I have no special insight into its development.  In this case, I see good reasons from a developer perspective to want "suspended" to be defined inclusively, but good reasons from standard writers' and implementers' perspectives to want it to be defined narrowly.

Comment: Alternatively, if one accepts that as the actual definition of thread suspension then one must conclude that POSIX requires a variety of functions to be implemented in terms of waiting on condition variables, but that it does not define whether other functions that may block in fact suspend the calling thread when they do so.

Answer (score 1):

read, fread, and friends are system calls and as such they will execute a context switch and execute from the kernel context until those functions complete. Interrupting a kernel context is outside the scope of pthreads thus they will not cause a cancellation.

I don't have a reference for it, but as far as I know, thread suspension in the context of Posix threads has to do with it's synchronization object's ( like futex's ).

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for arguments based on *documentation*, not based on particular *implementations*.

Comment: Uh, those syscall *are* interruptible. `man read: [...]It is not  an error  if  this  number  is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example [...]  because  read()  was interrupted  by  a  signal.[...] EINTR  The  call  was interrupted by a signal before any data was read; see signal(7).`